# Script runs strangely in interpreter. What is the effect of the -i flag?

Tags: python

I recently made a program which prints a word diagonally. Whenever I go to the console/python interpreter and type

`python3 "xxx.py"`, it will just continue onto the next line and won't do anything.

However, if I do: `python3 -i "xxx.py"` it enters python and lets me enter inputs for my program

Why is this happening?

My code (copied from comment below):

```
def diagonal(text, right_to_left = False):
    #Code for diagonal

diagonal()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "question1.py", line 17, in <module> diagonal() 
TypeError: diagonal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Comment: Please paste your code snippet and simple input/output. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: run `python xxx.py`  in cmd.exe, PowerShell, terminal, system console but not in Python Shell.

Comment: yes I did run it in the mac terminal and iterm2, same problem

Comment: Read the error...  `missing 1 required positional argument: text`... Read the method `def diagonal(text,`... Read how you call it `diagonal()`. What's missing?

Comment: Yeah I can put the arguments in, but the question I received told me that when the user will run "python file.py", it will enter the interpreter and then they can set what the values of text and whether right_to_left is true or not, so they should input "diagonal("text") if they want the text from left to right, and diagonal("text", True) if they want right to left. However, my code is only allowing me to enter the interpreter when I use "python -i "file.py"", I am new to python so I am confused

Answer (score 3):

The flag `-i` tells python to process the script, and then enter interactive mode. Without the `-i` python will just process the script and then exit.

A script might define functions, classes etc, but not call them. If you want the script to do something, you must have at least one line in your script that calls a function.

The usual pattern is:

```
#class and function definitions 
def print_diagonal(x):
    #code for diagonal

def main():
    #code for running the program
    word = input()
    print_diagonal(word)

#run the program
main()
```

The error you get is because the diagonal function has one required argument, the text. You need to supply this argument in some way. You could use an `input` function in the code (as in my example), or you could use the command line by `import sys`, and reading `sys.argv[]`. The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv) has examples of this

Comment: my code is similar, so the important bit is the "main()" at the end?

is there a way i can privately send you my code?

in my code, i'm making a program which prints a word diagonally either right to left or vice versa, and my defined function is "def diagonal(text, right_to_left = False):" and at the end I put diagonal() but I got this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question1.py", line 17, in <module>
    diagonal()
TypeError: diagonal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'